# Calculate a percentage in a update error operator multiply

Tags: c#, sql

I want to modify amount HT price according to a discount in my database.

But I have a problem for calculate the net price after discount.

I have this error

> The data type of the operand nvarchar is not valid for the multiply operator

Here is my code :

```
comm.CommandText = "UPDATE F_DOCLIGNE SET DL_DateBC = @date, 
DL_Remise01REM_Valeur = @remise, DL_PrixUnitaire = @pu, DL_MontantHT = 
(@remise * @pu) / 100 where AR_Ref = @code";

comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", textBox_livr.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pu", textBox_prix.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", textBox_art.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remise", textBox_rem.Text);

DL_Remise01REM_Valeur = @remise is the discount 
DL_MontantHT = (@remise * @pu) / 100 is my price calculate with the discount
```

Comment: Don't use `AddWithValue()`.  It has known problems with getting the right types.  Add with the specific type you need.

Comment: Convert `@remise` and `@pu` to number or use `.Add("@pu", SqlDbType.Int);` would be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gordon and Stuart have written in the comments, the problem is the fact that you are using `AddWithValue`.

When using `AddWithValue`, the compiler have to infer the data type of the parameter from the value (and meta data, if exists).
If you are using inline sql, you have no meta data, so the type of the parameter is decided by the [.Net framework to SQL Server mapping rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings) - and strings are mapped to `nvarchar`.

So instead of using `AddWithValue`, use `Add`:

```
comm.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = textBox_livr.Text;
comm.Parameters.Add("@pu", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox_prix.Text;
comm.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox_art.Text;
comm.Parameters.Add("@remise", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox_rem.Text;
```

Please note I've used `SqlDbType.Date` and `SqlDbType.Int` as a default, since I don't know the actual data types you are using in your table - much like the c# compiler I can't read into your database, so I have to guess.

For more information, read Joel Coehoorn's [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation, I have another error `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : This item is in use! The transaction ended in the trigger. The treatment was abandoned.`Do you know the solution, thanks again

Comment: I don't even know what language is that (I'm guessing French?)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to translate

Comment: I've never seen this error message before. I'm guessing you have a trigger on the table preventing you from doing what you try to do.