# Update 1 row using primary key

Tags: c#

I have a datagridview in form1, the user selects a row and relevant details are sent to the correlating textboxes in form2. from here the user clicks a button which should update a cell in the row selected (in the database) and change it to 'In production'(which is the orderstatus textbox.

I want to be able to update a row which correlates to the customer ID, which is a primary key in the database... currently the software updates everything within the database table ...

```
MAcon.Open();
OleDbCommand cm = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Customer Orders] SET [Order Status]=@OrderStatus WHERE [CustomerID]=@CustomerID", MAcon);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderStatus", textBox4.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", CustID.Text);
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
MAcon.Close();
```

Comment: What do you mean it updates everything in the database table?  More than one row? Or columns not listed in your SET statement?  If you copy/paste that query into management studio with the correct variable values do you get the expected result?  If not, what specifically is happening that you do not expect?

Comment: It is updating more than one row

Comment: What is the full structure of the database table?  What type of database is it?  How many records do you have in the table?  What do a sample of records look like?

Comment: If it updates more than 1 row, then your CustomerId field is not unique. and cannot be your Primary Key.  At least not by itself.  Does the table have just an an auto incremented identity field, maybe "Id".

Comment: What happens if you hard-code a customerid into your query. Does it produce the same problem? Are you sure there is no other code that you may have been testing without a WHERE clause?

Comment: I works correctly when i hard code in an ID- Does this mean anything?

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of the problem, but [you should be using `.Add`; not `AddWithValue`](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Consult [Update Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333613/).

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, bit hard to really know the problem without having some sort of definition of at the very least the Customer Orders table.

Taking an educated guess at it based on the info you've given us though, I'm assuming here that the customerID field on Customer Orders is a integer.

I would say, the issue is being caused by implicate type casting that is inherit in .AddWithValue().  CustID.Text will be returning a String so your where clause on the update statement will be comparing an integer value to a string which will never be equal.

You may have better results if you change your code to:

```
cm.Parameters.Add("@OrderStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox4.Text;
cm.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.Int32).Value = textBox4.Text
```

This is just of the top of my head, so syntax and types might be a little off